# Oracle sql Split String and extract data

Tags: sql, oracle

i have an oracle database with a column entry as the following:

```
{"Name":"Robert","information":"[200A1F0D00","Changed position from Dep1 to Dep2. Changed location from NewYork to Paris. Salary group switch from low to high."]}
```

The following result i want to generate with SQL:

| ID | Dep_old | Dep_new | Loc_old | Loc_new | salary_old | salary_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200A1F0D00 | Dep1 | Dep2 | New York | Paris | low | high |

How can I do this? I tried to use regex_substring functions, but it didn´t work out.
For now: this is my progress:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(f.EMPLOYEE, '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS a,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(f.EMPLOYEE, '[^,]+', 1, 3) AS b,
from Staff.EMPLOYEE f;
```

Can you please help me and create the query?
Best regards
dontknowguy

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a valid JSON string (you have `"[` when it should be `["`) then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT j.id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.info, 'Changed position from (.+?) to (.+?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS dep_old,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.info, 'Changed position from (.+?) to (.+?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
         AS dep_new,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.info, 'Changed location from (.+?) to (.+?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS loc_old,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.info, 'Changed location from (.+?) to (.+?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
         AS loc_new,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.info, 'Salary group switch from (.+?) to (.+?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS sal_old,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(j.info, 'Salary group switch from (.+?) to (.+?)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
         AS sal_new
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         value,
         '$.information'
         COLUMNS
           id   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH '$[0]',
           info VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$[1]'
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value BLOB CHECK (value IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES ('{"Name":"Robert","information":["200A1F0D00","Changed position from Dep1 to Dep2. Changed location from NewYork to Paris. Salary group switch from low to high."]}');
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DEP_OLD | DEP_NEW | LOC_OLD | LOC_NEW | SAL_OLD | SAL_NEW |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 200A1F0D00 | Dep1 | Dep2 | NewYork | Paris | low | high |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=44ddb9fac4beea42ca27a2b78a8d517c)*